# Can I use DHCPCD for dynamic IP router and static IP on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, dhcpcd

Can I use DHCPCD for dynamic IP on router and static IP on Raspberry Pi ?

The whole mess is due to the fact that I need dynamic IP on the router, because of the fact that I shared internet through my PC (I was able to do this with a bridge connection and dynamic IP on the router), and static IP on my Pi. (to ssh into it)

in `dhcpcd.conf` , how to setup these for tracking dynamic IP ?

```
static routers=⋯
static domain_name_servers=⋯
```

Comment: "I need static IP on my Pi" WHY? This question makes no sense - it doesn't look like any standard network setup. You need to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: As Milliways implies, this is probably not a good reason for a static IP: *"to ssh into it"*.  That's what [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) is for, and it is enabled by default on the Pi as well as most other computers, phones, etc.   That said, when it is easily possible it's harmless.  "Easily possible" is when you can configure *the router* to assign a static IP to the Pi's MAC address, because just doing it on the Pi is not a guarantee.  Unfortunately,  in this case it may not even be possible depending on how the internet connection is being shared:

Comment: ...You refer to "bridging", which implies that the Pi makes a direct link layer connection to the router and hence it's MAC address is passed through and dhcpcd can negotiate directly with the router.  However, that's not necessarily the case, eg., if the PC is really acting as a hotspot, it works via NAT and the MAC address are not passed though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I found the answer I was looking for both DHCPCD and Network Manager for my Pi Setup. If you close this question before I get the time to answer it, just know it's possible folks.